# How To Make Sequence Choice In Python

Tags: python

i try to make auto respond that have a sequence choice.

```
choice = ['welcome','welcome back','nice to see you','hai dude']  
>>> welcome  
>>> welcome back  
>>> nice to see you  
>>> hai dude  
>>> welcome  
>>> welcome back  
>>> nice to see you  
>>> hai dude
```

How to make a sequence choice from "welcome" until "hai dude" and go back to "walcome" again and again, before i am using random.choice() but now i need for sequence choice, can anybody give me advice ???

Answer (score 4):

You can use [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) by importing `from itertools import cycle`

```
In [3]: c=cycle(['welcome','welcome back','nice to see you','hai dude'] )

In [4]: next(c)
Out[4]: 'welcome'

In [5]: next(c)
Out[5]: 'welcome back'

In [6]: next(c)
Out[6]: 'nice to see you'

In [7]: next(c)
Out[7]: 'hai dude'

In [8]: next(c)
Out[8]: 'welcome'

In [9]: next(c)
Out[9]: 'welcome back'
```

**UPDATE**

```
from itertools import cycle
c=cycle(['welcome','welcome back','nice to see you','hai dude'] )
print next(c)
print next(c)
```

`next(c)` will give the next elements continously.

Comment: can you give me an example ? I try to use itertools.cycle(word) its not working

Comment: Is "word" is your list of string?if yes its ok..in your question it is "choice".so use "choice".

Comment: have any solution to replace random.choice() maybe sequence.choice() :):) ?

Comment: i try itertools.cycle('1','2','3') but global name 'itertools' is not defined

Comment: use random.choice() is very simple, but i need for sequence choice :)

Comment: i try def from itertools.cycle but that is not working

Comment: update full program in answer. use `cycle(['1','2','3'])`